# IdentityServer3 and AllowedCorsOrigins for file:// origin (cordova)

Tags: cordova, identityserver3

I am using InAppBrowser in a Cordova application to call the IdentityServer3 endpoints. It works fine in the emulator, but fails on the device.

I believe the issue is XHR calls failing because the device (Android) is running on host `file://` and this is presumably not a valid domain for the `AllowedCorsOrigins` property on the IdentityServer client.

I am 100% out of ideas and am posting this in desperation that I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS was a red herring (its not an issue from a file:// location in Cordova - only in a browser which may block it).

`xhr.responseType = "json";` was the issue - not supported in older versions of Chrome (and subsequently, I guess, my Android device).